# how to conditionally declare a type without function, based on boolean variable?

Tags: typescript

I tried reading the docs for Conditional type declarations, but I am missing something still.  How can I declare a type that is based on a conditional prop my component receives where I don't need to make a function to access the boolean?

Something like:

```
type ConditionalResponse =  myFlag ? CommonApiGeneric<{ items: SomeShape[] }> : CommonApiGeneric<{ entries: SomeShape[] }>;
```

[Here is a TS Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAYQPYFsVIHYEEoEsDiMGMATrgMYA8AKgHxwC8cA3qHO3FAIYDmMAXHAwBXFACNSAbjYcA5Nz4BaAM64AXjFmCR4qTPZgkYLgBttoiSWkgOcWYeMnFCmMq1CLekAF84AMjhqa1BcDDBSADMucngAZVQYWIALLlgWfThcABNzXSsMjC4UAThlMDIMHmtvUBCwyOj4AAUSJChldJsOFAgAMRNeAH5BMSQkExguDGrQAHpZuHJMMrgAWQhkFChMIjBGOAAKZjge-t44b0EWtuUASkZ6VhAM+bgAKg+4AAkAUQAlH4vBZJJAAd0WUzgAElSlwIPwgSc+gMeHBBohUOhsHhCMQyFRjrhwihlIJ4sVkqkYABtAC6F1oiNsgk2WJwBCIpAolGOuzIrjJCUpsDpDNqXXYr0gaWQGCyRNwmFMf1c2wwyngTFOKLRGLQmHZuK5BMyxNJcHJiRSIvp3noLMxBpxnPxPLgfNwAotQutNNttGCErgr2oSSIi2WongYDDGLlCqVJhVyjVGrgEhMYLghjgWRgEVC8AABlkuMYi6VfQig68luq9sdS8YADSZZQANVM2TLoVRviYwg1sVBJEosvlYEVhSTquWMFoRyZHAA1jB4XBhCQTM2l+wIjAwOQwyRBAd7gx6HwwCqAI7CVxgA7a87orBNKEAOh+ABkoQANKE-jgQQ30-JpvywWJViwAAmVtNxMW4dxrBZ2G8W5A1sWtlj2VpQQ6Jgmy4D8iI-XZPQ6dg3jgJASFzMtiNIokYBJdMuA1LIaIwOMJynZVZ3VeAkGEQ8EjgcUsIWEgD03bjKAAVRhWZGRAV5vCAA) that shows code example of what I am trying to do.

I believe I can fallback to a union type declaration, but this conditional would be very handy...

EDIT:   In the meantime, i have done this where my key is `[x: string]`:

```
const { data, isValidating } = useVaporSwr<
    OldPaginatedResponseGeneric<{
      [x: string]: ItemsShape[];
    }>
  >({
    key: url,
    fetcher: () => getRequest(isElixir ? API.ELIXIR : API.PLASMA2, url),
  });
  const key = isElixir ? 'items' : 'entries';
  const rows = data?.[key] || [];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the function generic and have the `myFlag` extend `true | false`. (Don't use `boolean`, because then you won't have the information you need to type the response correctly.) With that flag type, you can then specify the `CommonApiGeneric` you need and pass it.

I'd use `Object.values` to get the (only) value from the returned object, that way you don't have to mess with the differing response object shape.

```
const MyComponent = <T extends true | false>({ myFlag }: { myFlag: T }) => {
    type ConditionalResponse = T extends true
        ? CommonApiGeneric<{ items: SomeShape[] }>
        : CommonApiGeneric<{ entries: SomeShape[] }>;
    const { data, isValidating } = useSwr<ConditionalResponse>({
        key: url,
        fetcher: () => getRequest(myFlag ? API.ELIXIR : API.PLASMA2, url),
    });
    const rows = Object.values(data.data)[0];
```

Comment: ok.  any reason why the `<T extends true | false>` would not compile?

> Syntax error: Unexpected token

Comment: updated my original question with current workaround

Comment: That is because you are using React too in a TSX file. It thinks the generic is the start of a JSX expression. You can fix it by transforming `MyComponent` into a regular function (not an arrow function).

Comment: @PhilLucks That syntax compiles fine for me: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAsgTwMIgLYAdwFMywLwwA8AKjFgB5Q4AmEMUATgK5YwA+MAZgIYA2EWAHwAKAN4xUCAGK9uAcxgBfAFwxxkmfNWlFAShh5BagLAAoRQG4gA